# How to remove similar characters from an input tag in JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a Signup form.

In that, I have a username field that should not allow the characters `-, space, ", '` but I can't get that to happen.

I tried:- Slice method, substring method, regex, remove and split method and join technique.

So code:

```js
function username(event) {
    text = document.getElementById('usname').value;
    key = event.key;
    if (key == ' ' || key == '"' || key == "'" || key == '-') {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let final = text.slice(0, -1);
            document.getElementById('usname').value = final';
        },0.005)
    }
}
```

This was my best approach was this but it removed two characters at once and if we spam space and then type a character, we get a space in the text which is invalid.

Comment: Could you share the regex you tried? Because in this case, that looks like the best option to me. Also, I can try and improve on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expression [Regex]

This regex will accept only **alphabets** and **numbers** , and remove special characters and spaces.

```js
function username(event) {
  text = document.getElementById('usname').value;
  document.getElementById('usname').value = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\w]/g, "");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="username()" id="usname" />
```

**EDIT**

> [^a-zA-Z0-9\w] is the same as [^\w] or just \W. All will allow *, so
> [^a-zA-Z0-9] or [\W*] would be better. –  MikeM

You are right my friend, this much better.

```js
function username(event) {
  text = document.getElementById('usname').value;
  document.getElementById('usname').value = text.replace(/[\W_]/g, "");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="username()" id="usname" />
```

**EDIT**

> I don't want other symbols to be removed I just want these:- the dash(-), space, single and double quotes(',"). – Shaurya Shrimal

Add the symbols you want to remove in regex `/[-'" ]/g`

```js
function username(event) {
  text = document.getElementById('usname').value;
  document.getElementById('usname').value = text.replace(/[-'" ]/g, "");
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="username()" id="usname" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to give the best user experience to the user, you should inform the user with a hint text below the input box saying that these characters are not allowed.

It is recommended to have a validation on the input box, which will warn the user by highlighting the input box as red when the user inputs invalid characters, and not allowing to submit, rather than removing the characters from their entry without their knowledge.

For form validation, use a library like [validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) for detecting invalid characters. Example for validating username that should have only alpha numeric characters:

```
  validator.isAlphanumeric('fooBar123'); //=> true
```